# Javascript function to switch out images

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to make a simple function that switches out small images with a large image onclick.

The following setup works on the first click, but after that things go sort of haywire and images start switching out weirdly.

I have added an attribute to the small image elements called "data-largeSrc" that gets the url of a larger version of the image to use instead of the thumbnail when displayed at the larger size.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Html:

```
<div class="single-hero">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'single-hero', array('class' => 'hero-image')); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="image-gallery">
        <?php
        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('images') ){
            while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();
                $id = get_sub_field('image');       
                ?>
                <div class="image">
                <?php 
                $fullImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'single-hero');
                $attributes = array('class' => 'gallery-image', 'data-largeSrc' => $fullImg[0]);
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'gallery-thumb', false, $attributes);
                 ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            endwhile;
        }
        ?>
        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$('.gallery-image').on('click',function(){
      var big_src = $('.hero-image').attr('src');

      $('.hero-image').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-largeSrc'));  

      $(this).attr('src', big_src);
      $(this).attr('data-largSrc', big_src);

});
</script>
```

You can see the live page I'm trying to work with here: http://www.theatreoffjackson.org/sara-torres/project/45/test-project-1/

Comment: There is mistake in class name $(this).attr('data-largSrc', big_src) change it to data-largeSrc

Comment: In the words of Charlie Brown...."AAAAARRGH".... thank you. It works correctly now.